# How to implement function signature for fold() function related to Java?

Tags: java, function, oop, signature, fold

I am having problem to start the fold () function related to Java. Can you please help me to know how the structure of the fold function works. I am trying to use this method relating to generics of Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By "fold" you probably mean "fold left", which is another name for "reduce". The Java Stream interface defines `reduce`, so I suggest inspecting that signature:

```
T reduce(T identity, BinaryOperator<T> accumulator)
```